# Help proving dot product inequality

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces, inner-products

I have been struggling with a problem from my linear algebra class. It goes as follows:

> Let $V$ be a vector space with $\langle\,\cdot \mid \cdot\,\rangle$ dot product defined, and let $u, v, w$ be three distinct vectors in $V$. Prove that
> $$ 
> 2 \bigl| \langle u \mid v \rangle \bigr| \, 
> \bigl| \langle u \mid w \rangle \bigr| 
> \leq \|u\|^2 \bigl( \|v\| \, \|w\| + |\langle v \mid w \rangle \bigr|) 
> $$

I have tried to find a vector with norm equal to
$$
\|u\|^2 \bigl( \|v\| \, \|w\| + |\langle v \mid w \rangle \bigr|) 
- 2 \bigl| \langle u \mid v \rangle \bigr| \,
\bigl| \langle u \mid w \rangle \bigr|,
$$
but I haven't been able to do so. I have also got this equivalent expression:
$$
1 - 2 \cos(\alpha_1) \cos(\alpha_2) + \cos(\alpha_3) \geq 0, \
$$
where $\alpha_i$ are the angles between the vectors. Any ideas?

Comment: Assuming $|u|=|v|=|w|=1$ and $v=-w$ we obtain $|\cos^2 \alpha|\le 0$ which is not true in general.

Comment: We obtain again $2|\cos^2 \alpha|\le 0$. Are you sure we don't have some other condition?

Comment: Sorry again! There was an absolute value missing..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We may assume that $u,v$ and $w$ are unit vectors. The inequality in question then becomes
$$
2\big|\langle u,v\rangle \langle u,w\rangle\big|\le1+\big|\langle v,w\rangle\big|.
$$
Let $V$ be the inner product space in question. If $V$ is finite-dimensional, embed it in a higher-dimensional inner product space, so that we may assume that $\dim V\ge3$. Then $\operatorname{span}\{u,v,w\}\subseteq W\subseteq V$ for some three-dimensional inner product space $W$. Let $\{u,x,y\}$ be an orthonormal basis of $W$. Then we may write $v=a_1u+b_1x+c_1y$ and $w=a_2u+b_2x+c_2y$ where $|a_i|^2+|b_i|^2+|c_i|^2=1$. By Cauchy-Schwarz inequality, $|a_1a_2|+|b_1b_2|+|c_1c_2|\le1$. Therefore
\begin{align*}
2\big|\langle u,v\rangle \langle u,w\rangle\big|
&=2|a_1a_2|\\
&\le1+|a_1a_2|-|b_1b_2|-|c_1c_2|\\
&\le1+|a_1a_2+b_1b_2+c_1c_2|\\
&=1+\big|\langle v,w\rangle\big|.\\
\end{align*}

Comment: Thank you very much!